# TP-link TL-WN725N driver for 18.04 version

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, tp-link

Today I have updated Ubuntu version from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. After that Ubuntu doesn't recognized my Wi-Fi driver.
Kindly support to solve this problem.
Thank you.

```
vahe@vahe-Ubuntu:~/rtl8188eu$ lsusb    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0458:0708 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)     
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0458:0736 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)     
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub    
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Also I got below

```
vahe@vahe-Ubuntu:~/rtl8188eu$ sudo insmod 8188.ko
[sudo] password for vahe:     
insmod: ERROR: could not load module 8188.ko: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep mt76` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The driver have to be installed from sources
Open a terminal windows and go for it

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```

Comment: vahe@vahe-Ubuntu:~/rtl8188eu$ sudo insmod 8188eu.ko

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: Invalid module format.

I have got such error!

Comment: I don't believe 8188eu covers his 148f:7601 device, @Pareri Check: `modinfo 8188eu | grep 7601`

Comment: It looks like a Mediatek.

Comment: It worked on Ubuntu 18.04, Thanks

Comment: I am the only who faces no internet peridically on 18.04, i have 725n v3. Thanks

Comment: This driver works, but it caused my speed to drop even lower than it was before. It's a linux driver issue, when using my phone as wifi dongle, my speed is 5x though it's connected to the same router.