# TP-link TL-WN725N driver for 20.04 version

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, tp-link

I'm new to Linux, just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop. I tried the solution in [TP-link TL-WN725N driver for 18.04 version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047832/tp-link-tl-wn725n-driver-for-18-04-version), it didn't work for my adapter.

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
qiong@qiong-Inspiron-1320:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:1403 Syntek Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep mt76`:

```
qiong@qiong-Inspiron-1320:~$ dmesg | grep mt76
[   30.523017] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[   30.603487] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[   34.283847] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:09a8 failed:-110
[   37.707851] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:09a8 failed:-110
[   40.967860] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:0734 failed:-110
[   44.203845] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:42 off:0230 failed:-110
[   50.695839] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-110
[   53.963828] mt7601u 2-3:1.0: Vendor request req:02 off:0080 failed:-110
[   53.963883] mt7601u: probe of 2-3:1.0 failed with error -110
[   53.963948] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `dmesg | grep mt76`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ralink Tech MT7601U Wireless Adapter on Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205254/ralink-tech-mt7601u-wireless-adapter-on-xubuntu)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31 and user535733. I don't know why it says TP-link TL-WN725N printed on my wifi adaptor, but shows Ralink MT7601U with ```lsusb``` command.

Comment: Hi user535733, I tried the solution in your suggested question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205254/ralink-tech-mt7601u-wireless-adapter-on-xubuntu, but stuck at step 8, and get this output: ```qiong@qiong-Inspiron-1320:~/Downloads/mt7601u$ sudo su
root@qiong-Inspiron-1320:/home/qiong/Downloads/mt7601u# rmmod mt7601u (can output "module not loaded". if yes, ignore it and continue)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@qiong-Inspiron-1320:/home/qiong/Downloads/mt7601u# insmod ./mt7601u.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./mt7601u.ko: File exists
```

Comment: As you can see in your edit above, the module `mt7601u` is already loaded and exists in the default kernel. Compiling an older driver version won't likely help anything.

Comment: Is the device plugged into a USB2 port or USB3? Please try USB3. Then show us: `dmesg | grep mt76`