# Installing Device Drivers for TP-Link TL-WN725N Wireless Adaptor

Tags: drivers, devices, linux-headers, tp-link

I have purchased a TP-Link TL-WN725N wireless adapter and require to install its device driver to get it working. After perusing the product information sheet, I see that my current version of the Linux Kernel is not supported.

The closest solution I found was contained in the README.md file in this github repo:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

I receive a build error when executing the `make all` command. I surmise this is because I do not have the correct Linux headers installed, as highlighted by the github's readme.md.

I tried to install the headers by typing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

but am prompted with:

```
linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic is already the newest version (5.8.0-38.43~20.04.1).
```

I don't know what to do to get it to work and would appreciate some assistance. Since it would probably be asked of me, I have included the details of the following two commands:

> ```
> lsusb:
> ```

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0b2a China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

> ```
> dmesg|grep RTL
> ```

```
[    1.779449] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl, 14:da:e9:71:be:c0, XID 2c9, IRQ 27
[   30.768229] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-400:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-400:00, irq=IGNORE)
```

(A similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247379/tp-link-tl-wn725n-driver-for-20-04-version), however, the OP didn't respond when asked for more information)

EDIT:
The result of the following command

> modinfo r8188eu | grep 8179

is:

```
> alias:          usb:v07B8p8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* alias:        
> usb:v0BDAp8179d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

The result of the command

> `sudo modprobe r8188eu && sudo dmesg | grep 8188`
>
> ```
> [   15.389611] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
> [   15.391482] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
> [   15.453744] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
> [   15.499169] r8188eu 6-1:1.0 wlxd03745aa684a: renamed from wlan0
> [ 3987.294134] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
> [ 3987.385305] r8188eu 6-1:1.0 wlxd03745aa684a: renamed from wlan0
> ```

is:

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `modinfo r8188eu | grep 8179` If you get output like this: `usb:v0BDAp8179d*` then it shows that the needed driver is already included in kernel version 5.8.0-xx. Are there any clues in the message logs? `sudo modprobe r8188eu && sudo dmesg | grep 8188` also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help :-) Question has been edited. According to your comment, it seems my driver is already included.

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. The device is working. I had to select the network and click my wireless network and connect. I initially thought the wireless network wasnt picked up because all the signals were on *zero* and *grayed out* and thought it was a "cached view" when I still had the cable plugged in. Had you not pointed out to me that the headers were already installed, I would have gone down other rabit holes. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad it’s working by whatever means!